# File on SD card does not exists after reboot

Tags: linux, mount, memory, sd-card, corruption

I have a weired scenario on a Production unit. There is a SD card on the unit. I can create a file in the SD card and it shows that the newly created file exists there. I can do read/write operation on that file also. But when the unit is rebooted, this newly created file does not exists anymore. During unit boot-up, there are few SD card checks done by which it appears that there were some SD card issue and it got recovered.
Is there any way I can check whether the newly created file is saved or not? I need to make sure that the new file actually saved and it exists there even after the unit reboot.

[Edited] Is this SD card is really Bad? I have also tried to delete an old-existing file and do a unmount/mount of the SD card. But deleted file again appeared after remount.

Comment: What kind of Unit you are talking about? Are you able to issue mount/umount commands?

Comment: Yes, mount command works and shows the SD card as Rad/Write. Unit is a home security device,

Comment: What happens if you unmount the SD instead of a reboot? Will the file be there after mounting the SD again?

Comment: Created a new file, did unmount and mount again. New file does not exists after mount.

Comment: Thats odd. Can you please try to do the following? mount sd-card then create a new file. After that use the command `sync`. Than do the umount/mount again to see what happened.

Comment: Can you post the output from `mount`?

Comment: Yes thats odd. Looks like more of SD card issue? Did tried `sync` after creating new file, but result is same.

Comment: Here is the output of mount command: 
`....
.....
/dev/mtdblock2 on /nv type jffs2 (rw,relatime)
/dev/mtdblock7 on /dlcmtd type jffs2 (rw,relatime)
/dev/mtdblock10 on /dlamtd type jffs2 (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/sda2 on /usr/cisco_fmc_root/sys_fmc_sd_root type ext2 (rw,relatime,errors=continue)`. Here sda2 is the SD card that is causing the issue.